# Qual é a diferença entre abreviação e abreviatura?

Tags: abreviações

Qual é a diferença entre abreviação e abreviatura? São a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De modo objetivo e resumido:

"Abreviatura" é o encurtamento da palavra, tornando-a "cortada", isto é, com maior parte das letras retiradas, e com um ponto no final.
Exemplos: apto. (apartamento), Ltda. (Limitada), Cia. (Companhia), etc. (*et cetera*), entre outros.

"Abreviação" é a forma reduzida de uma palavra, mas sem deixá-la faltando letras ou com sílabas sem vogais, de modo que a palavra continue completamente compreensível.
Exemplos: moto (motocicleta), micro (microcomputador), foto (fotografia), entre outros.

Porém, "abreviação" também significa "redução", "encurtamento", sendo portanto abreviatura também uma abreviação/redução.

Comment: Alguma fonte para comprovar?

Comment: Usei [essa](http://www.mundoeducacao.com/gramatica/abreviacao-abreviatura-siglaqual-diferenca.htm) como base para ambos, [essa](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/abrev/) reforça a definição de abreviatura, e [essa](http://www.pucrs.br/manualred/abreviaturas.php) como base do último parágrafo.